# How do I add a handlechange to a todo app in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and making a todo app.

I have added an event listener(handleChange) to flip the todosData.completed from true to false and vice versa hereby allowing the user to check and uncheck the checkbox.

How can I rectify this. Here is my code:

```js
 class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: todosData
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed;
        }
        return todo;
      });

      return {
       todos : updatedTodos
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => (
      <TodoItem
        key={item.id}
        item={item}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
    ));

    return(
      <div>{todoItems}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

function TodoItem(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        type = 'checkbox' checked = {props.item.completed}
        onChange = {() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)} />
      <p> {props.item.task} </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: It took me some time to find the cause of this, which is also why I'm not going to mark this as a dupe, but it essentially is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62106596/reactjs-setstate-being-called-twice-in-a-function-called-once-why What's happening is that thanks to `<React.StrictMode>` wrapping your `<App>`, the function you pass to `setState` is fired twice, so the bool ends up having its previous value. This is a pretty evil pitfall imo. Anyway, the solution is to either not use [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), or pass the updated todos object instead

Comment: the problem I think is how you have assigned your event handler. Change it to the following handleChange ={() => this.handleChange(item.id)}

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier nope, OP's code is perfectly fine, your suggestion will break it

Comment: how will it break the code. if you assign the reference to the function the input that you get is the event object right and not the id.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier Something along the lines of `Undefined Reference: item` (did you mean to pass `props.item`? won't work either, because OP is expecting the `id` inside the function). All this is beside the point though, the issue is something else entirely, as outlined in my first comment.

Comment: you are right. I just saw the todo item code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @ChrisG in the comments, this happens when your component is wrapped inside `<React.StrictMode>`. If you created your application using Create React App this is done by default, check it on your `index.js` file.

StrictMode is a development feature that forces you to write better code. It only affects your development build, so your code should probably work if built and run in production mode.

One of the things that [StrictMode does is to run your `setState` method twice](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856), to make sure that you are not relying on it running only one time. So the first time it runs you invert your todo.completed as expected, and in the second time it reverts it back to the original value.

What this is telling you is that your `handleChange` function is actually updating state with a method that is not pure, since you actually change the `todo` object inside your `prevState.todos.map`.

What you need to do instead is to return a new `todo` object which will be a copy of the other, only with the `completed` property modified, like below:

```js
handleChange(id) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
      return {
        id: todo.id,
        task: todo.task,
        completed: todo.id === id ? !todo.completed : todo.completed
      };
    });

    return {
     todos: updatedTodos
    };
  });
}
```

Or using [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), like below:

```js
handleChange(id) {
  this.setState(prevState => (
    {
      todos: prevState.todos.map(todo => (
        {...todo, completed: todo.id === id ? !todo.completed : todo.completed}
      ))
    }
  ));
}
```

I believe this is a better solution than Chris G suggestion to remove <React.StrictMode>, since StrictMode actually helps you to write better code.