# The function inside setState((prevState) => newState) from useState hook gets called twice even setState is only called once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is just blowing my mind. Any reasons why this happens?

I couldn't replicate it with a simpler code snippet, I couldn't share as well the real gigantic code base. So this my best way to explain it:

I'm creating my own hook with its own state and some fuctions like this:

```js
const useHook = (args) => {
 const [state, setState] = useState([]);

 const createItem = (item) => {
   console.log("foo");
   setState((prevState) => {
     console.log("bar");
     // do some stuffs using args (no mutation done) 
     return [...prevState,item];
   }) 
 } 
 return createItem;
}
```

On a parent component:

```js
const createItem = useHook(otherState);

useEffect(() => {
  if (otherState) {
    createItem(validItemObject);
  } 
}, [otherState]);
```

Console Output:

```
foo
bar
bar
```

I tried removing everything on the setState and just left the console log and return the same state, still the same gets called twice.

```js
useState((prevState) => {
  console.log("bar");
  return prevState;
});
```

Together with that tried to provide an empty array on the useEffect dependecies so itll only called once onMount doesnt even need the other state since its just console.log, still gets triggered twice.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  createItem(validItemObject);
}, []);
```

What could be causing this to happen? Thanks, it might help me to find on the real codebase.

Comment: Isn`t it React.StrictMode - the wrapper of your App component? It is default for create-react-app.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62106596/reactjs-setstate-being-called-twice-in-a-function-called-once-why

Comment: @Fide yeah seems like it, it's working properly now thanks! I read through that thread as well I might have missed it.